# Histogram frequency count for column

Tags: unix, awk

I have a set of data (in the region of 800000 lines), in three columns (longitude, latitude and earthquake magnitude) that are not sorted in any way. A small example below...

```
-118.074 36.930 2.97
-118.005 36.898 2.61
-116.526 36.621 2.72
-116.488 36.650 2.68
-117.675 36.820 2.00
-117.963 36.514 1.30
-118.090 36.757 1.94
-117.651 36.518 1.40
-116.434 36.506 1.90
-117.914 36.531 2.10
-118.235 36.882 2.00
```

I am required to create a histogram of the earthquake magnitudes (in the range of 1.0 to 7.0), but I am not sure how to go about creating the frequency of magnitudes.

I understand that in order to create a histogram, I will need to discern the unique values, and set them in ascending order in a column. I believe I can then run a for command with a count function for each value... but I need a bit of help in doing so!

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: You just need to keep a counter for the last field: `{count[$3]++}`

Answer (score 0):

`awk '{counts[$3]++} END {for (c in counts) print c, counts[c]}' inputs.txt | sort -nk2`

will print the unique magnitudes and their counts in ascending order:

```
1.30 1
1.40 1
1.90 1
1.94 1
2.10 1
2.61 1
2.68 1
2.72 1
2.97 1
2.00 2
```